# Faster consumer in inadequate implementation of classical producer consumer

Tags: multithreading, synchronous, producer-consumer

Wikipedia provides an [inadequate implementation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Producer-consumer_problem#Inadequate_implementation) of the classical producer-consumer problem. In that implementation, the consumer is implemented as follows:

```c
procedure consumer() 
{
    while (true) { 
        if (itemCount == 0) {
            sleep();
        }

        item = removeItemFromBuffer();
        itemCount = itemCount - 1;

        if (itemCount == BUFFER_SIZE - 1) {
            wakeup(producer);
        }

        consumeItem(item);
    }
}
```

The wakeup call to producer is sent only when `itemCount == BUFFER_SIZE - 1`. If the consumer ran faster (e.g. got to consume twice in succession), would that mean the producer would never get woken up ?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using multiple threads then yes, suppose itemCount == BUFFER_SIZE for this example if there are multiple threads, then once you get to the line

```
if (itemCount == BUFFER_SIZE - 1)
```

There can be a context switch to another thread which removes another item, and so itemCount then equals BUFFER_SIZE - 2, and can only decrease. So wakeup(producer) is never called.

It should probably be itemCount <= BUFFER_SZIE-1.